# NetLogo: save or increase calculation time with using local variable "let"?

Tags: debugging, time, netlogo

I would like to save calculation time of turtle movement (question posted here: [NetLogo: how to make the calculation of turtle movement easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319606/netlogo-how-to-make-the-calculation-of-turtle-movement-easier)). In original move-turtles procedure authors use many "let" - local variables. I suppose that I can easily replace these "let" variables with built-in NetLogo primitives p.ex. here:

```
    ; original code with "let" local variables 

    let np patches in-radius 15                  ; define your perceptual range                         
    let bnp max-one-of np [totalattract]         ; max of [totalattract] of patches in your neighborhood                                     
    let ah [totalattract] of patch-here          ; [totalattract] of my patch
    let xcorhere [pxcor] of patch-here
    let ycorhere [pycor] of patch-here                                             
    let abnp [totalattract] of bnp                                                 
ifelse abnp - ah > 2 [ ...
```

can be replaced by this condition?

```
; make the same condition with NetLogo primitives

ifelse ([totalattract] of max-one-of patches in-radius 15 [totalattract] - [totalattract] of patch-here > 2 [ ...
```

Please, will utilization of "let" local variables save computational time or will it be more time consuming? How can I easily verify it? Thank you for your time !

(PS: Following comments to my previous question I suppose that primitives variables will be more efficient, I just prefer to be more sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the number of times each reporter is being calculated. If you say `let np patches in-radius 15` then that actually calculates the number of patches within 15 distance and gives that value to the variable named `np`. Using `np` in calculations directly substitutes the value that is saved. If you have to use it 10 times in your code, then using the `let` means it is calculated once and simply read 10 times. Alternatively, if you don't store it in a variable, then you will need `patches in-radius 15` at 10 different places in the code and, EACH TIME, NetLogo will need to calculate this value.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently is looks like local variables within [] works faster then primitives NetLogo variables.

Comparing **1) only NL primitives**

```
let flightdistnow sqrt (
;        (([pxcor] of max-one-of patches in-radius 15 [totalattract] - [pxcor] of patch-here ) ^ 2) + 
;        ([pycor] of max-one-of patches in-radius 15 [totalattract] - [pycor] of patch-here ) ^ 2  
;        )
```

vs **2) use local variables and then calculate turtle movement**

```
to move-turtles
    let np patches in-radius 15                  ; define your perceptual range                         
    let bnp max-one-of np [totalattract]         ; max of [totalattract] of patches in your neighborhood                                     
    let ah [totalattract] of patch-here          ; [totalattract] of my patch
    let xcorhere [pxcor] of patch-here
    let ycorhere [pycor] of patch-here                                             
    let abnp [totalattract] of bnp                                                 
    ifelse abnp - ah > 2 [              
       move-to bnp                        ; move if attractiveness of patches-here is lower then patches in-radius
       let xbnp [pxcor] of bnp                                 
       let ybnp [pycor] of bnp
       let flightdistnow sqrt ((xbnp - xcorhere) * (xbnp - xcorhere) + (ybnp - ycorhere) * (ybnp - ycorhere)) 
       set t_dispers (t_dispers + flightdistnow)                
       set energy (energy - (flightdistnow / efficiency))        
       set flightdist (flightdist + flightdistnow)
;               if ([pxcor] of patch-here = max-pxcor) or ([pycor] of patch-here = max-pycor) or ([pxcor] of patch-here = min-pxcor) or ([pycor] of patch-here = min-pycor)
;                 [set status "lost"                                    
;                  set beetle_lost (beetle_lost + 1)]
              ] ; if attractivity of [totalattract] is higher the the one of my patch
```

and using stop watch for movement of 5000 turtles my results are:

**- 1) 10 seconds
 -      2) 5 seconds**

so I suppose to use local variables in time consuming calculations.

I will appreciate if you will correct my conclusions if I'm wrong. Thanks !!

Comment: See Jen's answer. If using `let` means you avoid repeating an identical calculation, then you save time. Otherwise, you don't.